# SOLR Query similarto NOT IN (LIST)

Tags: solr, solr4

I have a requirement where we need to fetch the values like

**CustomerID NOT IN (LIST OF IDs Indexed) from SOLR Index.**

Can anyone suggest how can we achieve this using solr query?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Filter query `fq=-id:("id1", id:"id2")`
example

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/select?indent=on&q=querystring&wt=json&fq=-id:("id1", id:"id2")
```

Here it discards documents with list of IDs mentioned in filter query(fq) parameter

Answer (score 0):

`CustomerID:* AND NOT CustomerID:(ID1 OR ID2 OR ... IDn)`